# How do I control panel order in xyplot()?

Tags: r, lattice

R determines panel order in `xyplot()` by alphabetic order (for strings), or level order (for factors). I have dates as text which I would like to display in chronological order, rather than alphabetical order.

```
x <- sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE)
# overlapping 2010 and 2011
date <- rep(as.Date("2010-01-01") + sort(sample(200:400, 5)), each = 2)
striptext <- format(date, "%d-%b ...")
df <- data.frame(x, y, date, striptext)
```

This works fine:

```
xyplot(y ~ x | date, data = df)
```

But this puts the dates out of order:

```
xyplot(y ~ x | striptext, data = df)
```

I don't want the full date in the strips, but I do want them in correct order. Is there any solution besides making `striptext` an ordered factor?

Comment: The main point I think you are missing is that `striptext` is being coerced to a factor inside `xyplot` and if `levels` aren't supplied, the levels of the resulting factor are in alpha order. Consider `levels(factor(striptext))` and `levels(factor(striptext, levels = unique(striptext)))`. Real answer to your Q is get your conditioning variable set-up first as a factor with the levels ordered the way you want them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the levels of `striptext` explicitly and store it as a factor so that lattice doesn't have to do the coercion for you (which is where the levels end up in alpha order):

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE)
y <- sample(1:10, 10, replace = TRUE)
# overlapping 2010 and 2011
date <- rep(as.Date("2010-01-01") + sort(sample(200:400, 5)), each = 2)
striptext <- format(date, "%d-%b ...")
## set the levels explicitly
df <- data.frame(x, y, date, 
                 striptext = factor(striptext, levels = unique(striptext)))
xyplot(y ~ x | striptext, data = df)
```

Comment: That's it. By default `factor` will sort the levels, but `unique` leaves them in the order they are found.